# ImportError: .../python2.7/site-packages/Scientific/_netcdf.so: undefined symbol: H5P_CLS_FILE_CREATE_g

Tags: python, hdf5, netcdf, scientific-computing

I installed NetCDF in the allocated system by supercomputer center, but when I ran the python file, it shows: 
ImportError: /public/home/geosign/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scientific/_netcdf.so: undefined symbol: H5P_CLS_FILE_CREATE_g

ImportError:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "opt4.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ase.calculators.jacapo import Jacapo
  File "/public/home/geosign/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ase/calculators/jacapo/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ase.calculators.jacapo.jacapo import *
  File "/public/home/geosign/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ase/calculators/jacapo/jacapo.py", line 21, in <module>
    from Scientific.IO.NetCDF import NetCDFFile as netCDF
  File "/public/home/geosign/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scientific/IO/NetCDF.py", line 168, in <module>
    from Scientific._netcdf import *
ImportError: /public/home/geosign/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scientific/_netcdf.so: undefined symbol: H5P_CLS_FILE_CREATE_g
```

It seems that the _netcdf.so cannot find lib file of HDF5 (?) If I ran the job without installation of  zlib, HDF5 or NETCDF, I get the same error message. However, when I installed these software, there  is no error of the installation. All the software is configured with "--enable-share", and the LD_LIRBARARY_PATH was considered.

When I check the ldd of _netcdf.so, it shows：
(Seems cannot find the lib file of hdf5)

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff305fd000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002ad6970d5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002ad6972f1000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003fd0000000)
```

There is only one thing doubted... The HDF5 might not be successfully complied, since when installing it there are hundreds of similar warnings (however, since my major is not CS, I cannot fully understand it).

```
H5dbg.lo
H5dbg.c: In function 'H5_buffer_dump':
H5dbg.c:111: warning: will never be executed
H5dbg.c:113: warning: will never be executed
H5dbg.c:120: warning: will never be executed
H5dbg.c:108: warning: will never be executed
H5dbg.c:110: warning: will never be executed
H5dbg.c:118: warning: will never be executed
H5dbg.c:119: warning: will never be executed
H5dbg.c:109: warning: will never be executed
```

How I configured hdf5:

```
./configure --prefix=/public/home/geosign/usr --enable-hl --enable-shared --with-zlib=/public/home/geosign/usr  --enable-threadsafe --with-pthread=/usr
```

How I configured netcdf:

```
 CPPFLAGS=-I/public/home/geosign/usr/include LDFLAGS=-L/public/home/geosign/usr/lib ./configure --prefix=/public/home/geosign/usr --enable-netcdf-4 --enable-shared

    # NetCDF C Configuration Summary
==============================

# General
-------
NetCDF Version:     4.3.3.1
Configured On:      Thu Oct 22 14:48:45 CST 2015
Host System:        x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Build Directory:    /public/home/geosign/software/netcdf-4.3.3.1
Install Prefix:         /public/home/geosign/usr

# Compiling Options
-----------------
C Compiler:     /usr/bin/gcc
CFLAGS:         -g -O2
CPPFLAGS:       -I/public/home/geosign/usr/include
LDFLAGS:        -L/public/home/geosign/usr/lib
AM_CFLAGS:      
AM_CPPFLAGS:        
AM_LDFLAGS:     
Shared Library:     yes
Static Library:     yes
Extra libraries:    -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -ldl -lm -lz 

# Features
--------
NetCDF-2 API:       yes
NetCDF-4 API:       yes
HDF4 Support:       no
HDF5 Support:       yes
PNetCDF Support:    no
Parallel Support:   no
DAP Support:        no
Diskless Support:   yes
MMap Support:       no
JNA Support:        no
```

Thank you very much! I've been working on it for several days..So sad. :<

Comment: Have you add `/public/home/geosign/usr/lib` to `LD_LIRBARARY_PATH`? Like `export LD_LIRBARARY_PATH=/public/home/geosign/usr/lib:$LD_LIRBARARY_PATH`

Comment: Yes. I have done that... But it did not work...

Comment: I have not used Scientific._netcdf and I suggest You should also use python-netCDF4 (the Unidata hosted package) instead. For the latter, I declare external libraries during "pip install --allow-all-external <blabla>" and it works.